# What's the difference between 특징 and 특점?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I tried using 특점 in a sentence but was told 특징 might be more appropriate. Is there a difference? Here are the definitions from Naver's dictionary:

> 특점: [명사] 특별히 다른 점.
>
> 특징: 다른 것에 비하여 특별히 눈에 뜨이는 점.

I'm still not sure if I understand the nuance difference and why they wouldn't be interchangeable.

Comment: What was the sentence?

Comment: It's not about subtle nuances, or interchangeability. 특점 is just used extremely rarely, if not at all. You might want to use [특이점](http://m.krdic.naver.com/entry/39920800/?format=HTML&isMobile=true) though, as 특이점 and 특징 are roughly interchangeable.

Comment: @krim Thank you! Very good to know.

Comment: 특이점 also means "singularity" (either a mathematical singularity, or the OMG-robot-overlords-are-coming-to-us type): these days, I think 특이점 is more commonly used to mean "singularity" than "특징", although the latter reading is certainly possible.

Comment: Hmm, actually, I think there's a difference.  특이점 means "특이한 점" (something strange/noteworthy), slightly different from 특징 (characteristic).  So you could say "적의 기지를 감시했지만 특이점을 발견하지 못했다." (= didn't find anything noteworthy), but you can't use "특징" here.

Comment: @jick7 is completely right about the difference, as 특징 mostly means characteristic, while 특이점 can mean both characteristic and anomaly (though it is more often used as the latter - of which the meaning then expands into the *singularity* in some particular scientific contexts). That's why I commented they're **roughly** interchangeable.

Answer (score 3):

To be honest I kind of understand what 특점 means but I never used in my life or heard of it until I see this posting. 
Most of case I would use 특징 its almost same meaning but most people use 특징 instead of 특점.

Answer (score 1):

특징 = point distinguishing things

특이점=특이한 점=point in a thing A does not follow the governing
rule of A

I will enumerate 특징 of superman distinguishing from general people
:

(1) He has an arm like a steel

(2) He has an eye shooting laser

(3) He has a fast leg

(4) When he is with some green stone, then he sleep.

Here (1)-(3) are strong points of superman, but at (4), these are broken. Hence (4) is 특이점.